# Identifying what a woman is saying

Tags: pronunciation

Listening to a podcast, have some difficulty finding out what the woman is saying at one point. To me it's "I'll" at the beginning and then she makes a correction saying "we'll". But in the transcript it reads " Allright". Would you mind helping me with that?
https://vocaroo.com/1hHhdcoiFRHy

Comment: [*Indistinct interruption*]. I'll see you guys, er, next week when we'll talk about, er, people, er, you know, buying  bikes, er, and selling (?) their cars. [*Interruption: yeah*]. Why are Americans buying bikes and selling cars? [*Interruption: cool*].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She says:

> All right, we'll see you guys....

I think someone else says "and" just as she's beginning to speak, but there is no correction to "we'll".

Comment: I think the "Ehhhh" sound at the beginning might be the end of the last sentence she said.